How to extract Polygon Coordinates in order
Take a Polygon, and extract its PolygonCoordinates
polygonlist = Cases[Entity["PeriodicTiling", "SmallRhombitrihexagonalTiling"][EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]], _Polygon, All];
unitedpolygons = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[polygonlist], MaxCellMeasure -> 1]
ListPlot[PolygonCoordinates[unitedpolygons], Joined -> True]



Is there a way to get the vertices to be ordered as if you were travelling around the polygon. I.e.,
list={{-1.`,0.`},{-0.5`,0.8660254037844386`},{-0.5`,1.8660254037844386`},{0.5`,1.8660254037844386`},{1.3660254037844386`,1.3660254037844386`},{1.8660254037844386`,0.5`},{1.8660254037844386`,-0.5`},{1.3660254037844386`,-1.3660254037844386`},{0.5`,-0.8660254037844386`},{-0.5`,-0.8660254037844386`}};
ListPlot[list,Joined->True,AspectRatio->1]



note that this solution https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58211/ordering-the-boundary-points-of-a-polygon doesn't work because of the ConvexMesh

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/308508/72111

polygonlist = 
  Cases[Entity["PeriodicTiling", "SmallRhombitrihexagonalTiling"][
    EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]], _Polygon, All];

unitedpolygons = 
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[polygonlist], 
     MaxCellMeasure -> 1] // MeshCoordinates // Polygon // First

Graphics[Polygon[unitedpolygons]]


{{-0.5, 0.866025}, {-0.5, 1.86603}, {0.5, 1.86603}, {1.36603, 1.36603}, {1.86603, 0.5}, {1.86603, -0.5}, {1.36603, -1.36603}, {0.5, -0.866025}, {-0.5, -0.866025}, {-1., 0.}}


Or if you want all them separately.
polygonlist = 
  Cases[Entity["PeriodicTiling", "SmallRhombitrihexagonalTiling"][
    EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]], _Polygon, All];

First /@ polygonlist

Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], Polygon /@ %}]


{{{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 0}, {1/
   2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {-1, 0}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[
   3]/2}}, {{1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3]), 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[3])}, {1/
   2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 
   0}, {1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3]), -(1/2)}}, {{1 + Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {1, 
   0}, {1 + Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2)}}, {{1 + Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {1, 0}, {1/2, 
   Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3]), 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3])}}, {{1/2, 
   1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3]), 
   1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3])}}, {{1/2, 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/
   2}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}}}




The ordering of the coordinates is contained in MeshCells. For instance, GraphicsComplex[  MeshCoordinates[unitedpolygons],  MeshCells[unitedpolygons, 2]  ].  If one is unsure about the order returned by MeshCoordinates[].

This doesn't work for some tilings. e.g.
periodictilings = Entity["PeriodicTiling"] // EntityList;
polygonlist =
Cases[periodictilings[[39]][
EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]], _Polygon,
All];
Where 39 can be replaced with {40,18,22,27,29,30,31,32,38,40,42,47,49,51,57}

Also this:
Cases[Normal@Show[unitedpolygons], _Polygon, Infinity]


I would use MeshPrimitives, then pick the first polygon, and then the first argument is the list of points: MeshPrimitives[unitedpolygons, 2][[1, 1]]

This also doesn't work with periodictilings = Entity["PeriodicTiling"] // EntityList;
polygonlist =
Cases[periodictilings[[39]][
EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]], _Polygon, All];
Where 39 can be replaced with {40,18,22,27,29,30,31,32,38,40,42,47,49,51,57}
All, however, look fine in graphics.


Besides of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/308508/72111,
We can also directly use BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics and MeshPrimitives[#,1]&

g = Entity["PeriodicTiling", "SmallRhombitrihexagonalTiling"][
   EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]];
(* g=EntityList[Entity["PeriodicTiling"]][[39]][EntityProperty[\
"PeriodicTiling","PrimitiveUnit"]];  *)
list = MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@Show@g, 1, 
   "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]
ListPlot[list, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]


